# How to give condition in keydown DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview

I want to make a condition like this

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
}
```

If the user selects the first column it will execute `insert` and if they select the third column it will execute `edit`

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the selected columns, assuming they can only select one you can do this check

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[0] == dataGridView1.Columns[0])
{
    //Insert code;
}

else if(dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[0] == dataGridView1.Columns[2])
{
    //Edit code;
}
```

If they can select multiple columns you should first do this check as well

```
if(dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) == 1)
{
    if(dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[0] == dataGridView1.Columns[0])
    {
        //Insert code;
    }

    else if(dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[0] == dataGridView1.Columns[2])
    {
        //Edit code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to mark as the answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if( dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[2] != null)
{
    //Insertion
}
if( dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[0] != null)
{
   //Editing
}
```

Comment: If they select column 2, `dataGridView1.SelectedColumns[0]` will not be null